# How to compare strings in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code I am trying to compare two strings with jQuery. The current content of a div and the new content, loaded from a (currently) static page.

But it doesn't work, when the loaded content is the same as the current content, it still loads the new content...

When I view the content vars, they really are equal (I used the JS alert).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
        $.get("ajaxGetEvents.aspx", function (data) {
            if ($('#events').html() != data) {
                $('#events').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                    $(this).load('ajaxGetEvents.aspx').fadeIn('slow');
                });
            } else {
                alert("item is equal");
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: can we see your HTML?  What does this have to do with asp?

Comment: Have you tried == instead of !=

Comment: If there are any spaces in you HTML / Tabs, or whatever, it is shown as false. Try using `.text()` on both elements.

Comment: Keep in mind that unless you have headers set to ensure caching, calling `load` after calling `get` will load the content twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are not getting the values you expect for `$('#events').html()` and `data`.

Can you use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [developer tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359) to place a breakpoint at your if statement and inspect the values?

Alternatively you could just throw in a couple of alerts to see what these contain... Example:

```
alert($('#events').html());
alert(data);
if ($('#events').html() != data) {
```

That said, if you are not familiar with using firebug or developer tools, now might be a good time to start using them.  They will save you a lot of headaches in the future and they are infinitely better than alerts when it comes to debugging.

Comment: my created html in the loaded page uses `<br />` while the jquery.html() converts that to `<br>`

Answer (score 3):

maybe it's beter to compare the `.text()` instead of the (maybe generated) html

so you have

```
$("#events").text() == $(data).text()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ajax request return a normal text string (not html formated), I think you should use `text()` instead of `html()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
  $.get("ajaxGetEvents.aspx", function (data) {
    if ($('#events').text() != data) {
      $('#events').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).load('ajaxGetEvents.aspx').fadeIn('slow');
      });
     } else {
       alert("item is equal");
     }
   });
  }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the whitespaces are identical? Let's suppose `data` is `<span >test</span>`:

```
var data = "<span >test</span>";
// Temporarily place your data in a DOMElement to trigger parsing and re-serialization
alert(data===jQuery('<div>').append(test).html());
```

As you will see, the code above results in `false`. The reason is a space after the word `span`. Building a DOM tree removes such whitespaces and calling `html` does not have a way to restore them.

Note that this answer is just a guess. Please post your HTML to get more useful/targeted answers.